# Print JSON as a table in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the below JSON data and I am required to print it as a table. I have managed to come up with below query using jq in BASH to print the data in TOTAL section but unable to get headers including AN,BN part(whats the technical term?) of JSON. Total is equal to sum of sub values in it.

required format for output:

```
  Name           Total

    -----------------------------------

    AN        xxxxxxx

    BN        xxxxxxx
```

my current command:

`curl -s 'https://url.json' | jq '.[] | .total | "\(.confirmed)-\(.deceased)-\(.recovered)-\(.tested)"'`

DATA:

```
>     {   "AN": {
>     "delta7": {
>       "confirmed": 238,
>       "deceased": 2,
>       "recovered": 199,
>       "tested": 9953,
>       "vaccinated": 24243
>     },
>     "districts": {
>       "Unknown": {
>         "delta7": {
>           "confirmed": 238,
>           "deceased": 2,
>           "recovered": 199,
>           "tested": 9953
>         },
>         "meta": {
>           "tested": {
>             "last_updated": "2021-04-21",
>             "source": "https://dhs.andaman.gov.in/NewEvents/642.pdf"
>           }
>         },
>         "total": {
>           "confirmed": 5527,
>           "deceased": 65,
>           "recovered": 5309,
>           "tested": 357442
>         }
>       }
>     },
>     "meta": {
>       "last_updated": "2021-04-23T00:10:19+05:30",
>       "population": 397000,
>       "tested": {
>         "last_updated": "2021-04-21",
>         "source": "https://dhs.andaman.gov.in/NewEvents/642.pdf"
>       }
>     },
>     "total": {
>       "confirmed": 5527,
>       "deceased": 65,
>       "recovered": 5309,
>       "tested": 357442,
>       "vaccinated": 91977
>     }   }, {  

 "BN": {
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 238,
      "deceased": 2,
      "recovered": 199,
      "tested": 9953,
      "vaccinated": 24243
    },
    "districts": {
      "Unknown": {
        "delta7": {
          "confirmed": 238,
          "deceased": 2,
          "recovered": 199,
          "tested": 9953
        },
        "meta": {
          "tested": {
            "last_updated": "2021-04-21",
            "source": "https://dhs.andaman.gov.in/NewEvents/642.pdf"
          }
        },
        "total": {
          "confirmed": 5527,
          "deceased": 65,
          "recovered": 5309,
          "tested": 357442
        }
      }
    },
    "meta": {
      "last_updated": "2021-04-23T00:10:19+05:30",
      "population": 397000,
      "tested": {
        "last_updated": "2021-04-21",
        "source": "https://dhs.andaman.gov.in/NewEvents/642.pdf"
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 5527,
      "deceased": 65,
      "recovered": 5309,
      "tested": 357442,
      "vaccinated": 91977
    }   } }
```

Comment: AN in your example is a “key”.  Please ensure the sample data is valid as JSON in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines. In particular, the leading `>`characters should be removed. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

With your input (once it has been corrected):

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] |
  [.key,
   (.value | .total | "\(.confirmed)-\(.deceased)-\(.recovered)-\(.tested)")]|@tsv' input.json
AN  5527-65-5309-357442
BN  5527-65-5309-357442
```